# Prevent fixing body from scrolling to the top of the page

Tags: javascript

I have a button which prevents default and opens a modal. I am trying to make the background behind the modal stay fixed, and then unfix when the modal is closed.

The issue I am having is when I set the background to fixed:

```
if (modal.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    body.style.position = 'fixed';
}
```

the page in the background scrolls to the top, and when the modal is closed, the user isn't where they left off. To improve the UX, I would like the user to be returned to where they left off, so in my function I have:

```
const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;

if (modal.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    body.style.position = 'fixed';
} else {
    body.style.position = '';
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
}
```

The code above is triggered when the user clicks on the button to open the modal.

However, as the function is reloaded when the modal is closed, and the body position is 'fixed' has changed the scroll position to 0, this overwrites `scrollY`.

So, this can be solved one of two ways:

a) How do I prevent the scroll position from being changed to 0 when updating the body style position, or

b) how do I keep the value of `scrollY`?

Comment: You need to set scrollY every time the modal is displayed, but not when it's closed.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I have tried that also, and as it is set inside an if statement, when it reloads it says that scrollY is undefined

Comment: Hve you tried defining it in the outer scope so it stays defined when set in the inner function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution (thanks to the answers above for putting me on the right course, and to [@Constantin Groß](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995800/constantin-gro%C3%9F)'s comment):

Outside of my function I have declared `var scrollY;`

```
// Locks the background and makes it not scrollable
if (modal.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log("open " + scrollY);
    body.classList.toggle('popup-open--body');
} else {
    console.log("closed " + scrollY);
    body.classList.remove('popup-open--body');
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
}
```

And in my CSS:

```
.popup-open--body {
  overflow: initial;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

```
if (modal.classList.contains('is-active')) {
   body.classList.toggle('is-modal-open');
}
```

Somewhere at css:

```
.is-modal-open {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Setting the height to 100vh scrolls back to the top of the page for me (Chrome, Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the whole body to fixed positioning, you can do it for the modal instead and just set `overflow: hidden` on the body. This saves you the trouble of storing and restoring the scroll position upon opening/closing the modal.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.body.classList.add('show-modal');
}

function hideModal() {
  document.body.classList.remove('show-modal');
}
```

```css
#modal {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 display: none;
 padding: 3em;
}

body.show-modal {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.show-modal #modal {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
this is the top...<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
long content<br>
<button id="button" onClick="openModal()">open modal</button>

<div class="modal" id="modal"><button id="close" onClick="hideModal()">close modal</button></div>
```

Comment: Looks good on the snippet, but this isn't working in my project unfortunately. I've tried adding `overflow:hidden` to the body when the popup is open but the background is still scrollable.